# The >nul in Batch file doesnt mute

Tags: windows, batch-file

I started writing a program for autosave on a game and at the restoring file the >nul doesnt mute the output. The code below is from another file, but the rest doesnt matter, because it saves current progress and also creates restore batch so that you can go back to the point the save was made. When i checked the file, which gets created with this code, the >nul doesnt even transfer, it just puts the rest of the command

```
set curdt=%date:/=.%_%time::=.%
xcopy "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car" "Saves\backup_%curdt%" /i >nul
echo @echo off >> "Saves\backup_%curdt%\restore to this point.bat" 
echo echo Are you sure?(press any key to continue, close the dialog to cancel.) >> "Saves\backup_%curdt%\restore to this point.bat" 
echo xcopy defaultES2File.txt "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car" /y /w> nul >> "Saves\backup_%curdt%\restore to this point.bat"
echo echo Restoring....Be patient it will take several seconds. >> "Saves\backup_%curdt%\restore to this point.bat"
echo xcopy graveyard "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car" /y> >nul >> "Saves\backup_%curdt%\restore to this point.bat"
echo xcopy items "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car" /y> nul >> "Saves\backup_%curdt%\restore to this point.bat"
echo xcopy meshsave "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car" /y >nul >> "Saves\backup_%curdt%\restore to this point.bat"
echo xcopy options "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car" /y >nul >> "Saves\backup_%curdt%\restore to this point.bat"
echo xcopy trophies "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car" /y >nul >> "Saves\backup_%curdt%\restore to this point.bat"
echo echo Done! >> "Saves\backup_%curdt%\restore to this point.bat""
```

and btw %curdt% is a variable, setted to the current date and time (%date:/=.%_%time::=.%)

Here is what has to happen : a batch file to be created and to contain this:

```
@echo off  
echo Are you sure?(press any key to continue, close the dialog to cancel.)  
xcopy defaultES2File.txt "C:\Users\balvis\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car" /y /w >nul
echo Restoring....Be patient it will take several seconds. 
xcopy graveyard "C:\Users\balvis\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car" /y >nul
xcopy items "C:\Users\balvis\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car" /y >nul
xcopy meshsave "C:\Users\balvis\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car" /y >nul
xcopy options "C:\Users\balvis\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car" /y >nul
xcopy trophies "C:\Users\balvis\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car" /y >nul
echo Done! 
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
```

Comment: I am not understanding what you think the code should be doing.  Could you show us what your expected output should be.

Comment: your question title is `<nul` which is an *input redirection* and not output redirection

Comment: sorry, i did a typo

Comment: I edited it to see what should the result be

Comment: If you want redirect literal `>nul` to file, then use `^>nul`. The `^` escapes `>` to make it literal.

Comment: @michael_heath Thank you so much! That worked! Is there a way to mark your reply as answer?

Comment: Before fixing the issue you've reported, I'd consider making significant improvements to the code you want your created file to contain. All you are doing is copying six text files, you shouldn't be using xcopy.exe for that, (you could do it in one command).

Comment: yeah i know, but there are other files i need to exclude and about the exclude feature i didnt find a lot of info.

Comment: You use `Copy` for files, unless you're performing some complex tasks which require some of the special options available in a more complex command utility. That utility would invariably be `RoboCopy`, which was introduced as a built-in component, in Windows Vista, _(around 12 years ago)_, to supersede the now depracated `XCopy` utility.

Comment: Ok i will take a look at it ;)